# To prevent deleting of files from tmp after reboot in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Every time i reboot the /tmp folder get cleared. I store some logs in /tmp folder for my tests. I need them at least I copy those result after completion of tests. In some cases i need to reboot my nodes.

Answer (score 5):

That's an XY problem.

In short, don't store something you want on next boot in `/tmp`. Store it **elsewhere**. Like `/var/tmp`. Or your $HOME.

Beware that `/var/tmp` is nt to be used for permanent storage either, because it might be cleaned also, like every 30 days or so.

Comment: In 16.04 we can edit /etc/default/rcS (TMPTIME=-1) to disable that feature. Like that don't we have any solution in 18.04. I am trying to search the same file but it is not present in it

Comment: Please follow the advice in this answer instead of trying to alter the design.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting files on boot from `/tmp` is a recommended policy. That said, as the system administrator you are free to impose your own policy and deal with the repercussions.

Find the file `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf` and copy it to `/etc/tmpfiles.d/`
Edit the file `/etc/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf` and find the line:

```
  D /tmp 1777 root root -
```

and change the leading big-D to small-d (uppercase-D to lowercase-d).

Now your `/tmp` directory will not be cleaned on boot or any other time. You may wish to add timed cleaning (change the trailing `-` to the interval, such as `30d` for 30 days).

This is documented in the man pages: `man 5 tmpfiles.d`